# InvalidOperationException rendering ViewComponent in Strongly-Typed View

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

Recently updated dotnet core 1.0.1 to 1.1 and ViewComponent in MVC starts failing with the below exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: One or more errors occurred. (The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'App.Models.HomeViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'App.Components.LoginViewComponent'.)
```

The *Index.cshtml* renders **LoginViewComponent**:

```
@model App.Models.HomeViewModel
<html>
   @Component.InvokeAsync("LoginViewComponent")
</html>
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

The ViewComponent *LoginViewComponent/Default.cshtml* is just a class that displays it's model's info:

```
@model App.Components.LoginViewCompoent
<body>
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(v=>v.LoginName)</div>
</body>
```

**Views/Shared/Components/LoginViewComponent/Default.cshtml**

It renders fine when the **@model** directives is removed from *Default.cshtml*.

Isn't ViewComponent suppose to be separated and agnostic from the parent view that is wrapping it? From the exception it seems that it would be require to declare the **LoginViewComponent** ViewComponent in **HomeViewModel** class in order to render it.

Couldn't find any change note on this on asp.net core github.

Comment and help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you udpate dependencies as well ? (mvc 1.1.0 etc ...)

Comment: @agua from mars Yup, all of the _Microsoft.AspNetCore.* reference _ is on version 1.1.0

Comment: this looks weird to me : `@model App.Components.LoginViewCompoent`, is it a model or a component ?

Comment: @agua from mars: it's a strongly typed ViewComponent with the "LoginViewComponent" poco model.

Comment: Check my answer below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've came across the same error, someone in my team updated  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 and some of the components I had in Strongly-Type views started throwing

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type **'My.StronglyView.ObjectType'**, but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type **'My.ViewComponent.ObjectType'**.

I am not sure if this change was intentional, but it is definitely not what we would expect.

I haven't got the time to research about the reasons of this 'breaking' change but I came with a solution.

Thing is, if you pass a null object to your `ViewComponent.View()` method, we get this exception. Any non-null object passed through it, would update the ViewData.ModelExplorer and the correct *object-type* would have been registered, avoiding this exception.

Using Tester-Doer pattern, same pattern used in some classes of .Net Framework, We can now pass a non-null object to the `ViewComponent` and use it and its wrapped object as We need.

What I did was, I created a interface `IViewComponentModel<T>` as class `ViewComponentModel<T>` as below:

```
// Interface for ViewComponentModel
public interface IViewComponentModel<T> 
    where T : class
{
    T Data { get; }
    bool HasData();
}

// ViewComponentModel class for the Strongly-Type View Component
public class ViewComponentModel<T> : IViewComponentModel<T>
    where T : class
{
    public T Data { get; private set; }

    public ViewComponentModel(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public bool HasData() => Data != null;
}
```

In my ViewComponent class implementation, I return `View(new ViewComponentModel<AnyReferenceType>(myModel));`

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    var myViewData = _myService.GetSomeObjectForMyViewComponent();
    var model = new ViewComponentModel<MyViewDataType>(myViewData);

    return await Task.FromResult(View(model));
}
```

And finally, in my Component View (.cshtml) I have the code below:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model ViewComponentModel<MyViewDataType>
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this object inside of the view and to use your real model, just call `@Model.Data` and voilà.

In this way, We will never pass a null object to the ViewComponent and it won't 'inherit' the object type from the View.

Hopefully it helps!

[asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) [asp.net-core-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) [dotnet-core](/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) [asp.net-core-1.1](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1.1)

Comment: Yea.. couldn't find any info on the release notes. but cool.. i'll try it out. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is that, in ViewComponent class check null for view model, and if view model is null, then return empty Content result as following:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    var vm = some query for ViewModel;

    if(vm != null)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }

    return Content("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it will try to pass in the model of the "Parent View" ,not sure what you would call that, try updating your code like this

```
 @Component.InvokeAsync("LoginViewComponent", new App.Components.LoginViewComponent())
```

so that partial view can have what it needs, in order to serve up it's content.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work but i figure the workaround is to pass in an instantiated ViewModel instance in through the ViewComponent InvokeAsync method. Thanks though